# Place user-focused content in place with new content

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

The user is looking at the blue content and doing something with it. Then an AJAX call is made, and some new orange content is added to the top of the page. But since the blue content was already at the top of the page, the blue content has to move down to accommodate for the new orange content.

I would like to be able to force the blue content to stay where it is, and have the window push the orange + window top upwards.

Am I explaining myself adequately? I would have googled this but I don't even know where to start in searching for keywords.

Comment: You may find it easier on yourself and the user to open an editor as a "window" overlay overtop of the list of items. The list of items could be updated continuously underneath the overlay, but would not affect the overlay's position and size.

Comment: Another way to do it is to show a banner across the top of the page when new content is available, rather than just instantly updating the page. This gives the user the option of whether they are ready to see new content or just continue with the screen as is. This is how SO and Twitter, among others, handle this UX scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by scrolling by the height of the orange element once it's added. To do so:

- Use [`window.scrollBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) to scroll the window.
- Use [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) to get the height of the element.

Here is a demo (I added a bunch of mock content so scrolling is available):

```js
function addOrange() {
    // here you would do the AJAX call and get the orange content
    var orange = '<p id="orange">And I am orange!</p>';
    $("#blue").before(orange);
    window.scrollBy(0, $("#orange").outerHeight());
}
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }
button { background:#4488cc; padding:8px 16px; color:white; }
#blue { color:blue; }
#orange { color:orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p id="blue">I am blue</p>
<p><button onclick="addOrange()">Add text with AJAX</button></p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
<p>Mock text, just for filling...</p>
```

---

One issue with the solution above is that it doesn't work if there is no scrolling to do (e.g.: the element is at the top of the screen and the rest of the content doesn't fill in the screen).

One workaround for that would be to add a `margin-bottom` to the body to compensate for that. Something like this:

```js
function addOrange() {
  
    // add margin to the body to force scrolling if there isn't enough content to scroll
    if ($("html").height() < $(window).innerHeight()) {
        $("body").css("margin-bottom", $(window).innerHeight() );
    }
    
    // here you would do the AJAX call and get the orange content
    var orange = '<p id="orange">And I am orange!</p>';
    $("#blue").before(orange);
    window.scrollBy(0, $("#orange").outerHeight());
}
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }
button { background:#4488cc; padding:8px 16px; color:white; }
#blue { color:blue; }
#orange { color:orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="blue">I am blue</p>
<p><button onclick="addOrange()">Add text with AJAX</button></p>
```

You can also see it on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9wmoeux/1/).

Comment: Especially note: "*One issue with this solution: it doesn't work if there is no scrolling to do.*" You could calculate the total height of the window, the total height of the content, the total height of the new content and then add an empty div to the bottom of the page where `height = ( (total window height) - (total content height) ) + (new content height)`. However, choosing a UX solution that does not require scrolling the window may be a better choice in the long run.

Comment: How about checking the window height and the body height, and adding a margin-bottom to the body if its height is smaller than the window height? Something like this: `if ($("html").height() < $(window).innerHeight()) { $("body").css("margin-bottom", $(window).innerHeight() ); }`. That would force the scroll to appear and the element will be at the same position even when it's on top. Like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/p9wmoeux/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a content wrapper (let's say a `<div>`) and the "blue content" is wrapped in its own container within the wrapper, you would want to make your AJAX call, store the "orange content" in a variable, then use the `prepend()` method on the content wrapper to insert your new content as the first child, above the "blue content".

A simple example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="blue-content">
    <p>This is blue content</p>
  </div>
</div>

//save your AJAX result into a variable to use
var ajaxResult;
var $orangeContent = '<div id="orange-content">' + ajaxResult + '</div>';
$('div.wrapper').prepend($orangeContent);
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:$orangeContent.offset().top}, 'slow');
```

This would most likely be all in a function so it executes in sequence, but it would be contingent on how you implement it. You will see I added the `animate()` bit so that the window will scroll to the orange content once it is prepended to the wrapper.

That's a very basic example, but should lead you in the right direction.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer does not address the primary question, which is how to keep the "blue content" visible (within the window).

Comment: Edited to better address the question. However, your interpretation is off, since there is no mention of "keeping 'blue content' visible (within the window)"

Comment: "*But since the blue content was already at the top of the page, **the blue content has to move down** to accommodate for the new orange content. I would like to be able to **force the blue content to stay where it is**, and have **the window push the orange + window top upwards**.*"